# Update ToggleButtons on http response influtter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, togglebutton

[ToggleButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NJSS.png)

In flutter I have been using ToggleButtons (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html) with MVC architecture. An http request is send from the controller. I need to update a ToggleButton based on the response. The ToggleButton is changed with a list.
Example:  isSelected = [false, true];

How should i do it? Should I need to Change the boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

your toggle button should be inside of an statefull widget. In the state class you have to create a field for your boolean   eg. _isSelected

this field should be used for your toggle and your updates... after the response set your value and call setState() to refresh the whole widget

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution provided by Raegtime, you can consider using a `StreamBuilder` with a stream that periodically sends the HTTP request and builds your `ToggleButtons` accordingly, or if you only need to send the request once you can use a `FutureBuilder` instead. This way you won't have to use `StatefulWidget`s.

If you keep your business logic (that is, the function that does the HTTP request, or even the function that gets you the stream) in a separate file, this can offer a clean alternative, especially since you mention wanting to use a MVC pattern.